# ID generator comparison

Tags: java

I want to generate an unique ID within my application which can be used as a primary key for my database. The ID should be created by the application (and not by the database). I am wondering which method should I better use for that:

version 1:

```
// maybe faster and more memory friendly than version 2
// but what about collisions?
var uniqueId = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt()
```

or version 2:

```
var uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

or version 3:

```
// maybe the same as version 1
var uniqueId = new SecureRandom().nextInt()
```

or anything better?

Comment: The collision on the first version might be higher especially in a concurrent environment.

Comment: A UUID is the natural starting point. Do you have any reasons *not* to use UUIDs?

Comment: The first version might not create unique numbers and can therefore NOT be used as a primary key generator.

Comment: @RobertKock So you say, with version 1 collisions can likely occur?

Comment: Right, it's not an answer, it's a question. I'm curious if you have concerns about UUIDs, such as speed or memory usage--if so, could you elaborate on them? Or are you satisfied with UUIDs but just double checking that you're not missing anything?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I only want to know if **version 1 or 3** can be used as a serious alternative than **version 2**, and if not, why not. Clear question. Actually, I don't know how likely it is that **version 1** or **version 3** produce collisions.

Comment: Collissions are very unlikely but not impossibile. Murphey's law says that they therefore will occur often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both versions 1 and 3 will produce collisions, because there are only `2^32` different `int`'s. You need to calculate the probability yourself.

Regular UUIDs (version 2) are also random, but there is `2^128` of them, which means the chances of a collision are negligible.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the UUID, that is what I normally use.

You will know the number of characters that all the IDs have.

But it's my opinion, I don't think that there is any significant difference that you should choose one besides the other.